# Item not found on sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using graph api and running a for loop through a list of items, I then try to update the item and I keep getting a response telling me that the item was not found. The permissions say I should be able to view it and the because the names matched I'm thinking it should all work.

```
              var drives = await graphClient.Drives.GetAsync();
              var rootDrive = drives.Value[0];
              var items = await graphClient.Drives[rootDrive.Id].List.Items.GetAsync();
              foreach (var item in items.Value)
              {
                  if (item.Name == fileName || item.WebUrl.Contains(fileName))
                  {
                      var requestBody = new DriveItem
                      {
                          Content = fileBytes, 
                      };
                      var result = await graphClient.Drives[rootDrive.Id].Items[item.Id].PatchAsync(requestBody); //returns itemnotfound
                  }
              }
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a typo? Shouldn't it be `graphClient.Drives[rootDrive.Id].List.Items[item.Id].PatchAsync`? (the ".List" part is missing, probably you are trying to patch a drive, not a file)

Comment: I'm trying to patch the file. Adding .List changes it from a DriveItem to a ListItem, that fixed it from erroring out but it didn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` is `ListItem` and you want to update `DriveItem`, so you need `id` of `driveItem`.

When retrieving `items`, expand `driveItem` and return only `driveItem`'s `id` and `name`.

When calling patch, use `id` of `driveItem`

```
var drives = await graphClient.Drives.GetAsync();
var rootDrive = drives.Value[0];
var items = await graphClient.Drives[rootDrive.Id].List.Items.GetAsync((rc) =>
{
    rc.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "driveItem($select=id,name)" };
});
foreach (var item in items.Value)
{
    if (item.driveItem.Name == fileName || item.Name == fileName || item.WebUrl.Contains(fileName))
    {
        var requestBody = new DriveItem
        {
            Content = fileBytes, 
        };
        var result = await graphClient.Drives[rootDrive.Id].Items[item.DriveItem.Id].PatchAsync(requestBody);
    }
}
```